# Blocking mimikatz on the OS level?

Tags: windows, operating-systems, windows-server, windows-7, mimikatz

I want to know under which case would Mimikatz still run despite disabling WDigest?

Whether wdigest is set to 1 or 0, mimikatz still worked. (tested on Windows 7, 8, 2012)

Is there a better way to block it specifically on the OS level?

Answer (score 2):

*WDigest* isn't a setting which *disables Mimikatz*, it's a form of encryption supported by Windows, which when enabled, allows Mimikatz to *very easily dump plaintext passwords*.

Disabling WDigest removes that one type of credential from memory, but a user with Administrator-level privileges can still dump other forms of interesting credentials. Mimikatz has plenty of additional capabilities which don't rely on WDigest!

So what you're really asking looks like a meta-question: **How do I stop unwanted software running on my computers?**

And in short, the answer is to either enable security features available to you:

- Application whitelisting (AppLocker)
- Antivirus software which detects potentially unwanted applications
- Device hardening (particularly BitLocker (to prevent access to offline file systems) and if you can use Windows 10, Credential Guard)
- Reduction in user privileges (don't let users be Admins)

Or potentially require use of Windows 10 S Mode or a device which can only run Store-derived software (and lock the selection down).

Preventing any kind of unwanted software (like malware) requires a holistic approach.